# (C) Virtual network adapter

Tags: c, linux, networking, packet, data-processing

Is there any way in linux to programatically create a virtual network adapter that can be listened to, so that whenever an attempt is made to send data through the adapter, a method is called?

I am trying to forward all packets to a single ip address, then include their original location in the packet.

something like this:

```
void sendPacket(char to[], char data[])
```

So like if I ping google.com through the virtual network adapter, the method will be called like this `sendPacket("GooglesIp","Whatever data a ping sends")`

Comment: At what layer is sendPacket being called? The application layer? On top of TCP/UDP? Or IP? Or what? I ask because you can't do a ping through the normal socket send/recv. Its ICMP and at a lower layer. At what layer do you want your method to sit at?

Comment: I want to add a listener to call send packet :o

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a TUN/TAP device in Linux, which allows a program to act as a network interface.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP

You could then write a program to listen to that TUN/TAP interface for incoming data, and process it accordingly. Basically you would route the pings to the new TUN/TAP interface, then have a program read the packets off the interface, and route them from there.

Comment: Wow, I've been searching for at least an hour but after figuring out the term I find just what I need. Thanks!